# SQL Server 2008 R2 "Login failed for user" using remote connection

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dynamics-crm, workflow-foundation-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What string do I use to connect to an SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192258/what-string-do-i-use-to-connect-to-an-sql-server)

I'm trying to remotely execute a job on a local SQL Server 2008 R2 using a custom CRM Workflow activity in C#. However, when I run the workflow (using a username and password designed to have "all-access" in our domain, the following error occurs:

> Workflow suspended temporarily due to error: Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException:
>   Failed to connect to server hbssql2008.hbsys.com.
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.Connect()
>   at ExecuteSQLJob.ExecuteSQLJob.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
>   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
>
> Inner Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'hbsProcessAD'.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException 
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
>   String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject)

Here is the custom activity I loaded in:

```
namespace ExecuteSQLJob
{
    [CrmWorkflowActivity("A test activity to run SQL Jobs")]
    public sealed class ExecuteSQLJob : System.Activities.CodeActivity
    {

        #region Inputs
        [Input("Job Name")]
        [Default("BMS_ExtractTransformLoad")]
        public InArgument<String> JobName { get; set; }

        [Input("Server Connection")]
        [Default("-----")]
        public InArgument<String> ServerName { get; set; }

        [Input("User Name")]
        [Default("-----")]
        public InArgument<String> UserName { get; set; }

        [Input("Password")]
        [Default("-----")]
        public InArgument<String> Password { get; set; }
        #endregion

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            Server server = new Server(ServerName.Get(context));
            try
            {
                //Create server connection
                server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
                server.ConnectionContext.Login = UserName.Get(context);
                server.ConnectionContext.Password = Password.Get(context);
                server.ConnectionContext.Connect();
                //Find and execute the Job
                Job job = server.JobServer.Jobs[JobName.Get(context)];
                job.Start();
            }
            finally
            {
                //Close out of the server (if it managed to connect)
                if (server.ConnectionContext.IsOpen)
                {
                    server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have followed all of the instructions from [this website](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) to no avail.

**Thanks for any help!**

Comment: Let me guess... two different machines on the same domain, one running the workflow, the other running sql server.

Comment: Yes.  One server has dynamics crm 4 which runs the workflow while another server runs an instance of the sql server.  Both of the servers are here in my office and are on the same domain.